# How do NPM Package imports resolve?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, yarnpkg, monorepo

I have a monorepo with lerna, yarn workspaces, and the following structure:

```
- packages
  - a_webpack
    - src
      - index.ts
    - dist
      - main.js
      - main.css
  - b_tsc
    - src
      - indes.ts
    - dist
      - index.js
```

both packages `a_webpack` and `b_tsc` are to be consumed by another package `c`.

- on `b_tsc` i run `tsc` to compile into its dist folder.
- on `a_webpack` i run `webpack` to do the same

I mainly use webpack, because I can get a separate .css file in the dist that can be imported

When I import `b_tsc` in package `c` like:

```
import { something } from 'b_tsc'
```

everything works as expected.

Also when I do:

```
 import 'b_tsc/dist/main.css'
```

that is working.

However when i try:

```
import { something } from 'a_webpack'
```

I'm getting:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'a_webpack'
```

1. Question
   Even if I change the output of webpack to generate `dist/index.js`, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?
2. General Question
   When importing like seen above, how does the compiler know it needs to look inside `dist/main.js` or any other entry point within that package?

Comment: Technically, the way that Imports are resolved at runtime is dependent on your module loader. If you're using webpack, webpack is in control of the resolution of modules.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
The entrypoint is specified in the `package.json`s `main` property.

That solved the import issue for me.